# Checking for duplicate entries in array of objects and creating a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I'm trying to merge duplicate entries in an array of objects by creating a new array.

I don't know how to check for duplicated without looping through the new array, which then messes me up when trying to push stuff because it does it every time for the outer loop.

How should I do this properly?

```
var arr=[0];
for (var k in data) {
    var name = data[k].name;
    var item = data[k];
    //check if already in array
    for (var l in arr){
        if (arr[l].name == name){
            arr[l].value = arr[l.value] + ';;' + item.value;
        } else {
            arr.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you consider using Lodash? Your problem can be solved in one line. :)

Comment: Also note that `for..in` is for looping objects, not arrays.

Comment: How would I go about doing this with lodash?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **Lodash**

```
var arr = _.uniqBy(data, 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I'm answering your question right, but you could use .indexOf() to solve this. indexOf returns the position of an element in an array, or -1 if it doesn't exist: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

```
var oldArr = [1,2,2,2,3,4,5];
var newArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
    if (newArr.indexOf(oldArr[i]) == -1) {
        newArr.push(oldArr[i]);
    }
}

console.log(newArr);
```